# How can I change the system name from Linux to Windows in Debian?

Tags: linux, windows, debian, kernel, root

I have a good idea for me. So I want to be able to change the system name from Linux to Windows. So, if I views the specific website, that web site should get the my system name as Windows. E.g. Steam is automatically views to steam launcher download link for a currently using system. If this is the Windows, Steam views to us the own launcher as a executable file which extension is .exe. So if I change the system name from Linux to Windows, steam views to us that launcher for Windows in Linux. I want to be able to this. But not just for websites.

Comment: Note that most website detects the operating system in use by parsing your browser user agent, you may try changing your user agent.

Comment: To help what @Ruby said, [query for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+browser+override+user+agent).

Answer (score 1):

For a web browser, it is usually sufficient to change your user-agent string, since this is usually what websites do to detect the operating system you're using.  Most major extensions will also change other aspects of the browser, such as JavaScript APIs, to reflect the same values as the user-agent you've set.

For programs running on your computer, this is going to be harder.  Steam, for example, is a native piece of software and must necessarily know on what operating system it is to run.  As a result, this is not practically possible in all cases, although you could try running a native Windows version of the software under Wine.  I would not recommend such a configuration, though, since it is much less likely to work than a native version, and any software that contains tamper detection (e.g., many video games) may falsely view you as trying to tamper with the software if you run it under Wine.